# HTML flask To accept only integer input

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to accept only integer input using the int() function and the type to number with min set. But I noticed that when I give an input like 5.0 it should treat it as an invalid input and accept only integers.

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" min="0" name="shares" id="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="number">

def sell():
    """Sell shares of stock"""
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM tracker WHERE id=:id", id = session["user_id"])
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("sell.html", rows = rows)
    else:
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        shares = request.form.get("shares")
        if not shares:
            return apology("missing shares",400)
        if not symbol:
            return apology("missing symbol",400)
        lis = db.execute("SELECT * FROM  tracker WHERE id=:id AND name=:name", id=session["user_id"], name=symbol)
        share = int(shares)
        if lis[0]["no"] < share:
            return apology("too many shares",400)
        price = lookup(symbol)["price"]
        cost = price * share;
        saving = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=:id", id=session["user_id"])[0]["cash"]
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash=:cash WHERE id=:id", cash=cost + saving, id=session["user_id"])
        if lis[0]["no"] == share:
            db.execute("DELETE FROM tracker WHERE id=:id AND name=:name", id=session["user_id"], name=symbol)
        else:
            db.execute("UPDATE tracker SET no=:no where id=:id AND name=:name",no=lis[0]["no"] - share,id=session["user_id"], name=symbol)
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash=:cash WHERE id=:id", cash=saving+cost, id=session["user_id"])
        flash("Sold!")
        return redirect("/")
```

Comment: Your question implies that 5.0 failing is a problem, yet you say in a comment to an answer that you *want* it to reject 5.0. Which is it, and whats your problem?

Comment: Oh my bad. The problem is 5.0 should be treated as invalid input but 5 should be treated as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont' see the error code,however I guess is caused by the html input.

> > > UPDATE

Try this:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" step="0" name="shares" id="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="number">
```

---

> UPDATED:

Obviously you can instead run the check in Python, by doing something like:

```
symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
shares = request.form.get("shares")
if not symbol:
    return apology("missing symbol",400)
if shares:
    try: 
        shares = int(shares)
    except ValueError:
        error = 'It must be an integer'
        return redirect("/", error=error)
else:
    return apology("missing shares",400)
lis = db.execute("SELECT * FROM  tracker WHERE id=:id AND name=:name", id=session["user_id"], name=symbol)
if lis[0]["no"] < share:
    return apology("too many shares",400)
```

---

(For reference i leave the older answer)

Which won't work because shares would be a string

```
shares = intrequest.form.get("shares")
if isinstance(shares, float)):
    error = 'It must be an integer'
    return redirect("/", error=error)
```

This will work because first it checks if is a float or not, if it is then it will redirect , else you turn it a

Comment: but the behaviour i want is that it should reject if any float values are inputted including lets says 5.0 or 4.0

Comment: Yes i mistunderstood. By the using the same logic but adding step="0" it should do the trick, or handle it in the server side instead

Comment: I forgot to ask this: Since shares is a string I need to convert it into a float or int. But if  I do so I wont be able to use isinstance

Comment: You completely right about that one, i completely forgot that the request is a string.